# Excel VBA - Clear contents in a column between two row numbers using variables

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have one variable 'lastrow' which gives the row number of the last used row in a sheet. I also have variable 'lastrow2' which gives the row number of a row higher up on the sheet.

I need to clear the data in column AD, starting at lastrow2 and ending at lastrow.

How do I do this?

I have tried the below which I think is along the right lines but is not totally correct:

```
Worksheets("Received - Open").Range("AD & lastrow2":"AD & lastrow").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variables are a numeric data type, i.e. `Long`.

`Worksheets("Received - Open").Range("AD" & lastrow2 & ":AD" & lastrow).ClearContents`

If you include the variable inside the quotes it becomes part of the string. Make sure your variables are always concatenated in these scenarios and outside of the string.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do that:

```vb
Worksheets("Received - Open").Cells(lastrow2, "AD").Resize(lastrow - lastrow2 + 1).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat lastrow and lastrow2 as variables, not as constant strings

```
Worksheets("Received - Open").Range("AD" & trim(str(lastrow2)) & ":AD" & trim(str(lastrow))).ClearContents
```